# Run virtual environment using VMX in C++

Tags: c++, x86, virtual-machine, virtualization

I was curious if it's possible to start a virtual environment that can do something like this:

```cpp
int main() {
  std::cout << "This part is being ran on the host";

  StartVM();

  std::cout << "This part is being ran on a VM";

  EndVM();

  return 0;
}
```

I've read on some documentation on Intel-VT's VMX operations, but it's a level too far above my understanding of the intricacies of x86 hardware and x86 assembly.

I've tried to run the code in the [OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/VMX) but i'm having trouble trying to manually enable the corresponding bits in the article using inline assembly to make the `vmxon` instruction work.

If there's a library or an API in C++ (or even in C) that does this, please let me know. Also, if I'm deeply misunderstanding something about VMX or virtualisation in general, then please point me to the right direction.

Comment: VMX allows virtual machines to be a lot more efficient, and probably a little easier to write. But you still need to do quite a bit to support a virtual machine (e.g., every interrupt will result in a VMEXIT, so you have to write code to handle the interrupt on behalf of the VM).

Comment: Launching a VM is a privileged operation, most (all?) VMX instructions are privileged. So you definitely need a library coupled with a kernel component, which is off-topic. As already pointed out a VM is meant to virtualize all the hardware, so writing such a library will require some time. Plus, you would need to share the current C++ "context" with the sandbox? A VM is a brand new environment. So it's not clear where your sandbox starts and ends. E.g. What should `cout` do? If it's a sandbox it should not interfere with the host's `cout` right? Where should it print to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A research paper called dune implements what you describe.

- Paper: https://www.usenix.org/conference/osdi12/technical-sessions/presentation/belay
- Open Source Code: https://github.com/project-dune/dune

It achieves so with a kernel module that handles VM entries/exits and syscall forwarding. It also applies a bunch of (clever!) tricks that make the virtual memory space identical inside and outside the VM so the program can continue to execute after entering the VM.

Google's gVisor(https://gvisor.dev/) project may also help, and developers of gVisor are seeking to add the ability to transparently forward syscalls from VM in the kernel (https://lwn.net/Articles/902585/).